# Why did my cherry-pick fail?

Tags: git

After the failed cherry pick, it says that no `-m` option was given. What can I do to make the cherry pick work?

Terminal:

```
 git cherry-pick abcdeeee
 error: Commit abcdeeee is a merge but no -m option was given.
 fatal: cherry-pick failed
```

Comment: The error message said that no `-m` option was given. Why didn't you just try adding a `-m` option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apparently tried to cherry-pick a merge, which is a specific kind of commit (a commit with 2 parents).

To cherry pick this kind of commit you need to specify the option -m

Best regards,